# Evaluating Complex Numbers in Parsed Equations

Tags: swift, parsing, complex-numbers

I am trying to write a program for evaluating derivatives at a point using complex step differentiation [complex step differentiation](http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2013/10/14/complex-step-differentiation/)).

This involves taking some analytic function F(x) and evaluating it at some imaginary point F(x+ih) where h is some real parameter. F'(x) is then given by imag(F(x+ih))/h.

I have tested this method for evaluating derivatives using [this](https://github.com/dankogai/swift-complex) swift code for the complex numbers and it seems to converge on a solution much quicker than using finite difference methods is more stable as well.

I am however having a hard time figuring out how to implement this for user inputted functions that can be parsed.

I've tried looking into using DDMathParser however it does not support complex numbers. I was wondering if this would be possible at all using NSExpression however I don't understand how it works and I do not know if there would be any way of evaluating complex numbers with it.

If you guys have any idea of how to deal with this I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

DDMathParser author here.

As you can [see on Github](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/issues/45), I've considered adding support for complex numbers. The parser could be easily made to handle them I think. The problem is that the evaluation engine would need to be totally re-done. Right now all evaluations are done using `Doubles`, and it would be a non-trivial change to make them all support complex numbers.

`NSExpression` has no support for complex numbers either.

I think at this point you'll probably need to look somewhere else for your parsing and evaluation needs.